# Need help upscaling multi-dimensional Pytorch tensors

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have several Pytorch tensors ranging from 1-dimensional (e.g. `torch.Size([128]`), to 4-dimensional (e.g. `torch.Size([256, 128, 3, 3])`. Each tensor represents a weight in a neural network.

For each of these tensors I need to upscale 1 or 2 dimensions, for example

- `torch.Size([128])`to `torch.Size([256])`,
- `torch.Size([256, 128, 3, 3])` to `torch.Size([512, 256, 3, 3])`,
- `torch.Size([3, 256, 1, 1])` to `torch.Size([3, 512, 1, 1])`.

I've looked at `torch.nn.Upsample` or `nn.functional.interpolate` and similar functions but I can't find a good way to do this comprehensively for each of my problems other than hardcoding it.

In the case of the simple 1D example I'm looking for a scaled version of my original tensor, something like this:

```
 torch.arange(0, 9, dtype=torch.float32)
 t = torch.arange(0, 9, dtype=torch.float32)
 # = tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.])
 t_up = upsample(factor=2)
 # = tensor([0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5., 5.5, 6., 6.5 7., 7.5, 8.])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is very irregular as:

- `torch.Size([128])` to `torch.Size([256])` - 1D and interpolate everything
- `torch.Size([256, 128, 3, 3])` to `torch.Size([512, 256, 3, 3])` - `4D` and upscale first two dimensions
- `torch.Size([3, 256, 1, 1])` to `torch.Size([3, 512, 1, 1])` - `3D` and upscale only second dimension **without the first**

There is no clear way around "hard coding" in this case and "clever" approaches would probably only raise eyebrows when someone is going over your code.

- Your `1D` example uses `linear` mode with `align_corners=False`, not sure about `4D` examples, but those would require `bilinear` mode at least.
- `size` for `torch.nn.functional.interpolate` flattens `1` dimensions for some reason, hence only `scale_factor` is an option.
- Some of the data has to be reshaped for interpolate

All in all, hardcoding and some comments are the best option in this case as there is no clear way to group different ways of expanding tensors you are given (and trying to be smart in this case is probably a dead end).

Comment: thanks, the first 2 are actually doable with `Upsample`. I haven't found a proper solution to the third problem though, where either of the first 2 dimensions needs upsampling.